# How to price a custom mortal stunt?

Tags: gm-techniques, dresden-files

I've got a couple of players that want to create a custom stunt or two, which I'm fine with.  However, I'm not really sure on how I should price the cost of their stunts based on what it allows them to do.  What are the general guidelines for custom stunt creation and pricing the stunt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the book, stunts should only cost 1 refresh point, since they're supposed to be weaker than supernatural powers. Its aim is to give a pure mortal an equalizing effect towards supernatural beings, and an advantage over the common Joe. But if you think the stunt created is powerful, you could limit its use and have them pay a fate point for its use as well. (Ex. "Killing Blow")